# Can I mark an HTML entity inside of a Django-outputted select box as safe?

Tags: django, escaping, html-entities

I have a drop down box on my Django form that contains the `&reg;` HTML entity.  Is there an easy way to get Django to mark it as safe?

This doesn't work:

```
{{ form.myoptions.label_tag }}
{{ form.myoptions|safe }}
```

Edit:

I should mention that the drop down box is generated from a `ForeignKey` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - it doesn't work... I suppose the easiest way is to mark it safe from python.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

MY_CHOICES = [
    ('foo', mark_safe('&amp; foo')),
    ('bar', 'bar'),
]
```

According to the source it looks like you can either define a `ModelChoiceField.choices` manually or write a new field and override `label_from_instance`.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foo'].choices = ((foo.id, mark_safe(foo.bar)) for foo in Foo.objects.all())



class SafeModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj): 
        return mark_safe(obj)
```

I think I prefer constructing the choices myself so that any other magical `ModelForm` `field -> form field` conversion isn't overwritten.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a drop down box generated from a ForeignKey field?

Comment: Oh wait, `ModelChoiceField` uses queryset, not choices. Let me go dig into how it converts the QS into choices..

Comment: Yes, it looks like you can either 1: manually construct choices for the field, or 2: subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance` to `mark_safe`.